# What does theta do?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, lwjgl, slick2d

So I've found this class called Vecter2f in Slick2D and inside of it there is a method called getTheta. I don't know what this does but I got the source to the method if that will help. And what use is this method?

```
public strictfp double getTheta() {
    double theta = StrictMath.toDegrees(StrictMath.atan2(this.y, this.x));
    if ((theta < -360.0D) || (theta > 360.0D)) {
        theta %= 360.0D;
    }
    if (theta < 0.0D) {
        theta += 360.0D;
    }

    return theta;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns the(noramlized) angle(in degrees) that the x-axis forms with the segment connecting the given point and the origin of the coordinate system. So when the point is converted in [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form), this function returns its [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [following right-angled triangle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ttrig.html):

[image: RIght-angled triangle]

Given `Rx` and `Ry`, the function computes `θ`. The result is expressed in [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29) and is normalized to `[0; 360)`.